# Write image to pdf with PDFBox, found there are some strange pixels on the left top corner

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I'm using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to write an image to a pdf. The image is a just a pure red rectangle.

The image is:

[image]

My code is:

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDRectangle pageSize = new PDRectangle(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
PDPage page1 = new PDPage(pageSize);
doc.addPage(page1);

File imageFile = getRedImageFile();
PDXObjectImage pdImage = new PDPixelMap(doc, ImageIO.read(imageFile));

// write front image
PDPageContentStream contentStream = null;
try {
    contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page1);
    pdImage = parseImage(backImage, doc);
    contentStream.drawXObject(pdImage, 0, 0, CARD_WIDTH / 2, CARD_HEIGHT / 2);
} finally {
    if (contentStream != null) {
        contentStream.close();
    }
}
```

The final image is:

[image]

It's not clear, so I zoomed it in and upload another:

[image]

Why there is such strange pixels there?

Comment: Can you embed the original image here?

Comment: The original image is just a prue red rectangle, all pixels are red, not other color.

Comment: A picture paints a thousand words..

Comment: It would be useful that you file a bug in PDFBox JIRA if the bug still exists today, even if you think that this is "just a red rectangle". Alternatively, send me the image file.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a contentstream bug. You can probably get around it by closing and then opening the stream again after writing your image, but that can cause more bugs (such as overwriting all fonts).

The workaround I used was to start every page with a placeholder image 50000 pixels to the right of the page. Since this image got corrupted and not the others, everything was fine.